# Elif statement showing when I dont' want it to

Tags: python

I'm trying to get it so that the elif statement only shows when the input isn't 1,2,3,4. We just learned about if and elif statements so I'm still a little uncertain about them. Currently the elif statement shows regardless of the number I put in.

```
Season=input("Pick a number.(1,2,3,4): ")
if Season.lower()=='1':
    print('Winter is cold.')
if Season.lower()=='2':
    print('Spring is warm.')
if Season.lower()=='3':
    print('Summer is hot.')
if Season.lower()=='4':
    print('Fall is cool.')
elif Season.lower():
    print('error')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lower()` is unnecessary since that function is used to change uppercase letters to lowercase. For your situation, you want the input to land into 4 different cases where any other case gives an error. To do this, you can restructure your `if` cases. The first `if` checks the condition, if it fails, it then goes down in order and then checks the next `elif`. This continues down the list. If the very last `elif` fails, then it falls into the `else` section.

```
Season=input("Pick a number.(1,2,3,4): ")
print(Season)
if Season == '1':
    print('Winter is cold.')
elif Season =='2':
    print('Spring is warm.')
elif Season =='3':
    print('Summer is hot.')
elif Season =='4':
    print('Fall is cool.')
else:
    print('error')
```

Answer (score 0):

Current `elif` is only the alternative for the last `if`. So after you do all the other `if` statements, you check - is it `4`? if yes, fall is cool. If no, then you check if it's not empty (e.g. if it's 1, 2, 3, 7, 13...) then error. If it's empty you won't get any output.

You need `elif` instead of `if` on all of them except first; and you need `else` instead of the last `elif` because I don't think you wanted to see if lowercased input is empty.

Furthermore, note that lowercasing a number like `"1"` you still get the same string: `"1"`. Thus, the lowercasing operation is useless here. It is not an error, but can be a cause of errors in further maintenance as it increases complexity needlessly, and more complexity results in higher programmer error rate. It also causes code to be very, very slightly slower.

I also chose to change your `Season` to `season` because Python convention is not to use title case for variables. Title case should be used for class names. Sometimes uppercase is used for variables when translating formulae, e.g. `L`; but that is also not the case here.

```
season=input("Pick a number.(1,2,3,4): ")
if season=='1':
    print('Winter is cold.')
elif season=='2':
    print('Spring is warm.')
elif season=='3':
    print('Summer is hot.')
elif season=='4':
    print('Fall is cool.')
else:
    print('error')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all the `if`s starting from the second one to `elif`, and the latest `elif` should be `else` (therefore removing `Season.lower()` from the `else` line too)

In this case, when the number is either 1, 2, or 3, all the cases will be `True` on the `elif` statement (as `bool(x)` for any non-empty strings returns `True`)

You might wanted to study about control flow a bit further.

By the way, `.lower()` is not needed in this case, and variable names should be in all noncapital letters.